# App crash in Android M

Tags: android, api, actionbarsherlock

My app always work fine, but now is crashing in the new Android M preview I think that the problem is with the ActionBarSherlock. Someone have the same problem or know how can I fix it?

This is the error:

```
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.messaging.android/com.myapp.messaging.android.holo.messagelist.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$HoloActionBarSherlockNative> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock>
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$HoloActionBarSherlockNative> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock>
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.wrap(ActionBarSherlock.java:240)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$AddonSherlockA.getSherlock(AddonSherlock.java:53)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$AddonSherlockA.installDecorView(AddonSherlock.java:60)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity$1.action(_HoloActivity.java:587)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity$1.action(_HoloActivity.java:1)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at org.holoeverywhere.addon.IAddonBasicAttacher.performAddonAction(IAddonBasicAttacher.java:167)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.performAddonAction(Activity.java:497)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.requestDecorView(_HoloActivity.java:584)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.setContentView(_HoloActivity.java:604)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.myapp.messaging.android.holo.messagelist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:120)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6162)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     ... 9 more
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$HoloActionBarSherlockNative> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock>
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.wrap(ActionBarSherlock.java:232)
07-31 10:41:59.435: E/AndroidRuntime(4239):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: I think its something to do with android M making reflection  follow the access rules for private methods so it cant create the class. I dont know how to fix it though and face the same issue, did you make any progress?

Comment: @Chris.D Definitely it is a reflection issue. For some reason the constructors were not accessible through reflection. We had to make it accessible constructor.setAccessible(true); Please see the answer below for more info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the exactly same issue today and fortunately I was able to fix it.
This fix has to be done in actionbar sherlock library code. So you need to add actionbarsherlock as library project.

Make the following change in ActionBarSherlock.java

```
ctor.setAccessible(true);
```

add above line just above return ctor.newInstance(activity, flag); (line no 230 in public static ActionBarSherlock wrap(Activity activity, int flags){} method.

Similarly do following change in LayoutInflater.java

```
constructor.setAccessible(true);
```

add this just above final View view = constructor.newInstance(args); (line no.352) in public View _createView(String name, String prefix, AttributeSet attrs){}

Note: I am using ActionBarSherlock 4.3.0