# ActionBarSherlock crashes my app on Android 6.0

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-holo-everywhere

I have an app that was written a couple years back that I am in the process of maintaining. The app uses HoloEverywhere and ActionBarSherlock to provide certain functionality back  to older versions of the OS. Until recently there have never been any problems with this, so it was quite a shock to see support complaints about the app crashing on startup this week. These crashes are all on Android 6.0 devices and all come with the following exception message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laridian.pocketbible/com.laridian.pocketbible.PocketBibleMainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$HoloActionBarSherlockNative> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$HoloActionBarSherlockNative> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock>
at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.wrap(ActionBarSherlock.java:238)
at org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$AddonSherlockA.getSherlock(AddonSherlock.java:54)
at org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$AddonSherlockA.requestWindowFeature(AddonSherlock.java:159)
at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity$24.action(Activity.java:515)
at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity$24.action(Activity.java:1)
at org.holoeverywhere.addon.IAddonBasicAttacher.performAddonAction(IAddonBasicAttacher.java:122)
at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.performAddonAction(Activity.java:505)
at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:512)
at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.onInit(_HoloActivity.java:491)
at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.forceInit(_HoloActivity.java:227)
at org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:225)
at com.laridian.pocketbible.PocketBibleActivity.onCreate(PocketBibleActivity.java:126)
at com.laridian.pocketbible.PocketBibleMainActivity.onCreate(PocketBibleMainActivity.java:1180)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<org.holoeverywhere.addon.AddonSherlock$HoloActionBarSherlockNative> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock>
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.wrap(ActionBarSherlock.java:230)
... 24 more
```

So I know something has changed with regard to these libraries. However, I'm not sure what I can do about this. Is there a new version of ActionBarSherlock that is compatible with Android 6.0? Is there a version of HoloEverywhere that will work for Android 6.0? Is there something I'm missing here? Or am I going to have to go back and rewrite my whole app to support Android 6.0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744752/app-crash-in-android-m
Try this, it worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with an old version of a deprecated library. HoloEverywhere stopped to use ABS like 2 years ago. ABS was deprecated long time ago too. No one support to those libraries right now.

My tip: remove your HoloEverywhere dependencie. Then embrace Material and/or move your minSdk to 15.

If you can't do that: update to the last version of HoloEverywhere. This is the faster fix, but you are working with a deprecated library...

Comment: Have you actually tried the latest version (2.1.0 at that time) or was it just an indication or assumption that it would work?

Comment: It was an assumption. But know I know that the las version of HoloEverywhere have serious issues on 6.0. Please, stop using it.

Comment: I was going to but I wasn't sure why you said the latest works (since it was released pre-2015).